# Is VC++ runtime needed for simple console applications?

Tags: visual-c++, software-distribution, prerequisites

I wonder if I need to distribute VC++ runtime when I only write simple console applications using Visual C++ 2015.

No DLLs etc... just static linking of the standard library (and my own libraries).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can self-service this: use a clean VM OS installation to check.

But, the answer is: no. be sure to set c/c++ > code generation > runtime library to Multi-threaded or Multi-threaded Debug, as appropriate. Generally during development, it's convenient to use dependency walker periodically to verify your exe isn't importing any DLLs.